# Index of permutation with sorted constraint

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to find a bijective mapping between a permutation and an index. The permutation refers to a 4-tuple of integers.

Tuples consist of $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $a,b,c,d \in [1;15]$ with $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$. For instance, these are possible:

- `0,0,0,0`
- `0,2,7,8`
- `8,9,15,15`

And these, for instance, are not possible:

- `1,0,0,0`
- `0,1,2,1`

I would like to map these tuples to an index and back. As an example:

- `0,0,0,0` $\leftrightarrow 0$
- `0,0,0,1` $\leftrightarrow 1$
- ...
- `0,0,0,15` $\leftrightarrow 15$
- `0,0,1,0` $\leftrightarrow 16$
- ...
- `6,15,15,15` $\leftrightarrow k$
- `7,7,7,7` $\leftrightarrow k+1$
- ...
- `15,15,15,15` $\leftrightarrow 3876$ (19 choose 4)

The order given above is not the only one, I am perfectly fine with any bijective mapping as long as it is not too computationally expensive. Can you help me find a formula?

Some background: I'm using this idea to compress sorted lists of integers. Right now I use a loopup table for translation, but it is rather large, so I am hoping to find a way with only rather elementary calculations. (But just out of curiousity, I would also love to see how this can be generalized to different numbers of elements and larger value ranges.)

The number 3876 (total number of valid combinations) is from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/965141/246), I also confirmed it experimentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(a,b,c,d)=\binom{d+3}{4}+\binom{c+2}{3}+\binom{b+1}{2}+a$$
Or, if your binomial function doesn't like $\binom{3}{4}=0$, use this:
$$f(a,b,c,d)=\frac{d}{4}\binom{d+3}{3}+\frac{c}{3}\binom{c+2}{2}+\frac{b(b+1)}{2}+a$$
Either way, the values are mapped like this:

- `0,0,0,0` $\leftrightarrow 0$
- `0,0,0,1` $\leftrightarrow 1$
- `0,0,1,1` $\leftrightarrow 2$
- `0,1,1,1` $\leftrightarrow 3$
- `1,1,1,1` $\leftrightarrow 4$
- `0,0,0,2` $\leftrightarrow 5$
- `0,0,1,2` $\leftrightarrow 6$
- ...
- `2,2,2,2` $\leftrightarrow 14$
- `0,0,0,3` $\leftrightarrow 15$
- ...
- `14,15,15,15` $\leftrightarrow 3874$
- `15,15,15,15` $\leftrightarrow 3875$ (This is $\binom{19}{4}-1$ because the first index is $0$)

Notice that this mapping is expandable. You can increase the max value without affecting the mapping of lesser values: `0,0,0,16` $\leftrightarrow 3976$

The reverse, finding a tuple given its index, involves quartic and cubic equations and is probably easiest with look-up tables. The tables are small, just $16$ elements for each of $b,c,d$, and can also be used in place of the above function as they contain the pre-calculated values of the binomials.

$L_d(0\text{ to }15)$ holds the values $L_d(d)=\binom{d+3}{4}$

$L_c(0\text{ to }15)$ holds the values $L_c(c)=\binom{c+2}{3}$

$L_b(0\text{ to }15)$ holds the values $L_b(b)=\binom{b+1}{2}$

Given index $x$, find the greatest value $d$ for which $L_d(d)\le x$

Then let $x=x-L_d(d)$ and find the greatest value $c$ for which $L_c(c)\le x$

Then let $x=x-L_c(c)$ and find the greatest value $b$ for which $L_b(b)\le x$

Finally, let $a=x-L_b(b)$

Using the tables to find the index:$$f(a,b,c,d)=L_d(d)+L_c(c)+L_b(b)+a$$

Comment: Excellent and very helpful answer. I tested and confirmed it works fine. Can you briefly explain how you arrived at the first line?

Comment: @mafu Years ago, I needed to map number pairs $(a,b)$ to unique indices. As I wrote the list in this particular order, I noticed the relation of $b$ to the triangular numbers. This yielded $f(a,b)=\binom{b+1}{2}+a$. Some time later, I attempted to modify the formula to work for $3$ variables and found that $f(a,b,c)=\binom{c+2}{3}+f(a,b)$, and this pattern continues for any number of variables. $f(a,b,c,d,e)=\binom{e+4}{5}+f(a,b,c,d)$ and so on